# ruby comparison of time and variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models, being an Employee and a WorkingPattern. An instance of an Employee belongs_to an Working Pattern.

The Working Pattern looks like this

```
        :id => :integer,
      :name => :string,
       :mon => :boolean,
       :tue => :boolean,
       :wed => :boolean,
       :thu => :boolean,
       :fri => :boolean,
       :sat => :boolean,
       :sun => :boolean
```

I need to know if an Employee should be at work today. So, if today is a Tuesday and that employee's working pattern record reports that :tue = true then return true, etc. I don't have the option of renaming the fields on the WorkingPattern model to match the days names.

I know that

```
Time.now.strftime("%A")
```

will return the name of the day. Then I figured out I can get the first 3 characters of the string by doing

```
Time.now.strftime("%A")[0,3]
```

so now I have "Tue" returned as a string. Add in a downcase

```
Time.now.strftime("%A")[0,3].downcase
```

and now I have "tue", which matches the symbol for :tue on the WorkingPattern.

Now I need a way of checking the string against the correct day, ideally in a manner that doesn't mean 7 queries against the database for each employee!

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `%a` for the abbreviated weekday name. And use `send` to dynamically invoke a method

```
employee.working_pattern.send(Time.now.strftime("%a").downcase)
```

Comment: the method `.wday` also returns the week day of the date/datetime/time

Answer (score 1):

Use `send` to invoke a method, stored in a variable, on an object.

Both of these are identical:

```
user.tue # true
user.send('tue') # true
```

Comment: thanks for this - your post was the one that enabled me to understand what was going on with send.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an attibute using `[]`, just like a Hash. No need to use `send` or even `attributes`.

```
day = Time.now.strftime("%a").downcase
employee.working_pattern[day]
```

Answer (score 0):

Butchering strings makes me feel a little uneasy

Construct a hash of day numbers:

```
{0 => :sun
 1 => :mon,
 2 => :tue,
  ...}
```

Then use `Time.now.wday` (or `Time.zone.now.wday` if you want to be timezone aware) to select the appropriate value from the hash

You can then use that string on `employee.working_pattern` in any of the ways described by the other answers:

```
employee.working_pattern.send(day_name)
```

employee.working_pattern.read_attribute[day_name]
enployee.working_pattern[day_name]